# How can I solve the Plex error, 'The server "SubhensHmSvr" is unavailable'?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, samba, media-server

I have installed Plex on my Pi 3 using https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-plex-server/

The installation works fine and able to get onto Plex. But when I am trying to access Plex and connect to server, getting following error:

The server "`NameofPiServer`" is unavailable
Plex will automatically try to reconnect to this server.

I am not sure what's causing the issue. I have piVPN and Samba running on my Pi.

Comment: Where are you connecting from(LAN or Wan)? What do the Plex [logs](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200250417-Plex-Media-Server-Log-Files) say.

Comment: The tutorial you link is odd to me. I've never seen the method they use to set a static IP before. You should be using dhcpd or reserve an addr in your router. Anyway I'd bet address resolution is the most likely cause of your problems.

Comment: I use Plex with openmediavault (seperate image). It works quite well with my raspberry pi 2